# SQL result doesn't show the date when the day value is higher than 12

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following code in my SQL:

```
   CASE WHEN ISDATE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,t1.RequestedDeliveryDate,@dateformat)) = 1 
        THEN CASE WHEN YEAR(t1.RequestedDeliveryDate) >= 2000 
                  THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,t1.RequestedDeliveryDate,@dateformat) 
                  ELSE '-' 
             End 
        ELSE '-' 
    END AS [Requested delivery]
```

If the date in the field [t1.RequestedDeliveryDate] has a day value less than 12, the result shows the date.
When the day value is above 12, it shows the hyphen.

@dateformat is an integer, set to 105

Why?
What am I not seeing here/ doing wrong?

rg,
Eric

Comment: Sounds like your 'day' is really a 'month'

Comment: What you think is the day is the month, and what you think is the month is the year. When you pass 13 as a month your else statement is executed.

Comment: And if you use 101 as the convert format, does the problem go away?

Answer (score 0):

SpectralGhosts answer did the trick.

I replace the first @dateformat with 101 and problem was solved.